# How to override the ACPI entries for I2C tuning values and use custom I2C tuning values?

Tags: linux-device-driver, acpi

Currently, the I2C tuning values (`HCNT`, `LCNT` & `SDA_HOLD_TIME`) are being passed as ACPI entries in the DSDT with static timings as follows:

```
Device (I2C0)
{
    Name (_ADR, 0x00150000)
    Name (_DDN, "Serial IO I2C Controller 0")
    Name (SSCN, Package () { 432, 507, 30 })
    Name (FMCN, Package () { 72, 160, 30 })
}
```

But I want to use some custom I2C tuning values for my platform board and hence want my driver to override these values coming from ACPI entries. How to override these ACPI entries and use a quirk so that the driver can use custom I2C tuning values? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to enable `CONFIG_ACPI_TABLE_UPGRADE` and attach your updated excerpt to *initrd*.

Comment: That's a good choice. However, I am looking it more from a driver perspective so that I can expose these I2C tuning values as _sysfs_ entries so that I can fine-tune them on the fly. Currently, I have a quirk in place that overrides the values coming from `ACPI` table:                        `if (has_acpi_companion(&pdev->dev))            dw_i2c_acpi_configure(pdev);`

Comment: Is it some test setup? In production one doesn't need to tune these values run-time. Thus, described method should be enough. Otherwise you indeed need an ugly hack.

Comment: There are numerous platform variants coming out of a specific platform. Each variant is requiring a different set of I2C tuning values to work with. Since the BIOS is same across the variants, it is getting difficult to modify the ACPI entries in BIOS everytime for tuning the I2C values, hence this driver override quirk.

Comment: Wait, the discussed values are host specific. I barely get how they can be different from platform to platform. Can you elaborate what kind of setup requires such change and why?

Comment: As per your patch: [link](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/0343b2f4e4a52c907d7676ce3159e0b5e7f0301c), some Intel Broxton based platform variants are requiring different set of _I2C_ tuning values than the ones provided by _BXT_ _BIOS_. If I use the _ACPI_ provided values, I am encountering a _lost_ _arbitration_ _error_ while _I2C_ _Fast-mode_ communication.

Comment: Regarding to the commit message those platforms **do not provide** such information at all. Otherwise it will be used. So, mentioned patches for the driver fixes the issue for the Broxtons. What is your case? Why is it different? P.S. If you think there is a bug, please, submit the report to the mailing list.

Comment: The commit message was just an example and not to be taken in totality. In my case, the values ( _HCNT_, _LCNT_ and _SDA HOLD TIME_ ) are coming from ACPI entries and I just need to override them in my driver. My case is different because the Silicons are yet evolving for my platform. Its an internal requirement and I don't think of raising it as a bug.

Comment: Ah, fair enough. In such case perhaps you stick with your own solution.